# Unable to get the correct pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to change this table here

```
name     occupation
samantha    doctor
julia   actor
maria   actor
meera   singer
ashley  professor
ketty   professor
christen    professor
jane    actor
penny   doctor
priya   singer
```

output I need to get in columns order of  Doctor, Professor, Singer,Actor-

```
Jenny    Ashley     Meera  Jane
Samantha Christeen  Priya  Julia
NULL     Ketty      NULL   Maria

I tried


Select [Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor]
 From (Select Occupation,NAme From Occupations) Pivot (Max(NAme) For Occupation in ([Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor]))a;
```

Comment: Please include sample data _directly in the question_.

Comment: I changed the tag to mssql

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select max(case when occupation = 'doctor' then name end) as doctor,
       . . .
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by occupation order by name) seq
      from table
     ) t
group by seq;
```

Comment: Can You explain you code a little bit, I am confused

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Occupasions TABLE(
  name VARCHAR(100),
  Occupation VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Occupasions VALUES
  ('samantha', 'doctor'),
  ('julia', 'Actor'),
  ('samantha', 'Singer'),
  ('tuhin', 'doctor'),
   ('ketty', 'professor');



SELECT  [doctor],[Actor],[Singer],[professor]
FROM (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM @Occupasions
) as t
PIVOT (
    MAX(Name) FOR Occupation IN ([doctor],[Actor],[Singer],[professor])
) as pvt
```

Comment: max(Name) will only give maximum(Name) , how will I get all names in a ocupation

Comment: have you checked my query ?

Comment: I didn't check .I am asking for a bit more explanation

Comment: COde is working fine but can you explain me how with the use of max(name) I am getting all names sorted but not just a single name,

Comment: if you want to understand pivot please go through https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233325&seqNum=4 , hope you will get all things .. if answer is ok then i think you should accept the answer for  appreciation

Comment: I'm asing question to get an explanation for the answer,I already know the answer

Comment: @AdityaMatturi ok got it

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @r1=0, @r2=0, @r3 =0, @r4=0;
SELECT MIN(Doctor), MIN(Professor), MIN(Singer), MIN(Actor) FROM
(SELECT CASE Occupation WHEN 'Doctor' THEN @r1:=@r1+1
                       WHEN 'Professor' THEN @r2:=@r2+1
                       WHEN 'Singer' THEN @r3:=@r3+1
                       WHEN 'Actor' THEN @r4:=@r4+1 END
       AS RowLine,
       CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Doctor' THEN Name END AS Doctor,
       CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Professor' THEN Name END AS Professor,
       CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Singer' THEN Name END AS Singer,
       CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Actor' THEN Name END AS Actor
       FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY Name) AS t
GROUP BY RowLine;
```

Link: https://nifannn.github.io/2018/06/01/SQL-%E7%AC%94%E8%AE%B0-Hackerrank-Occupations/